# Fork the pipeline of aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have several similar aggregation operations at the same time, for example

```
db.cases.aggregate([
   {$match : query},
   {$unwind : "factors"},

   //operation 1 of the above result
   // ...
])

db.cases.aggregate([
   {$match : query},
   {$unwind : "factors"},

   //operation 2 of the above result
   // ...
])
```

The first two stages of aggregation( `$match`, `$unwind` ) are the same, and I think it would be a waste to repeat the duplicate stages. So I am asking if there exists a way to forking the pipeline, so that it can share the result from the first two stages, as follows,

```
db.cases.aggregation([
   {$match : query},
   {$unwind : "factors"},
   forks : [
      {... operation 1},
      {... operation 2}
   ]
])
```

Answer (score 3):

This was a while ago but just so you know it was implemented:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/

```
{ $facet:
   {
      <outputField1>: [ <stage1>, <stage2>, ... ],
      <outputField2>: [ <stage1>, <stage2>, ... ],
      ...

   }
}
```

Comment: Not exactly. It is important to note that the output of `$facet` is **always** a single BSON Document. This means the complete content is limited to 16MB and has the normal constraints. The intended use of the pipeline stage is funny enough for "facet counts and data". Which is typically a very small set of structured results that may indeed be sourced as the results of several aggregation pipeline expressions. But is is certainly **NOT** related to what the question is talking about, nor should it ever be applied to anything other than a "summary" result.

Comment: I don't think your copy and pasted reply is related to what I am saying. I was just noting that this general feature is out. " nor should it ever be applied to anything other than a "summary" result" is also a very opinion based statement. You can use it for many things beyond a summary result. Do you have an answer to his question? One possibly inefficient way without facet being the first stage might be to do his initial stages and out into a temporary collection to then work over. But all of this depends more on his framework and setup than we currently know.

Answer (score 0):

as this looks like a very good functional proposal - Mongo at this stage does not have such a functionality.

If the queries are heavy on server you could consider using `$out` stage after all similar pipeline entries, and then querying newly created collection.

**edit**

mondo jira ticket:  https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-24804

Comment: Not exactly. It is important to note that the output of `$facet` is **always** a single BSON Document. This means the complete content is limited to 16MB and has the normal constraints. The intended use of the pipeline stage is funny enough for "facet counts and data". Which is typically a very small set of structured results that may indeed be sourced as the results of several aggregation pipeline expressions. But is is certainly **NOT** related to what the question is talking about, nor should it ever be applied to anything other than a "summary" result.