# Get data between stages in an aggregation Pipeline

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Is it possible to retrieve the documents between stages in mongo aggregation pipeline?

Imagine that I have an aggregation pipeline running in pymongo with 10 stages and I want to be able to retrive some info available after stage 8 that will not be available on the last stage. Is it possible?

The idea is quite similar of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38047527/fork-the-pipeline-of-aggregation), and looking at the answers I found this [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) but it wasn't clear for me if the `stage1` of all `outputFields` are the same then it will be executed only once and perform as expected. And also, as I saw on the docs, `$facet` does not support indexes, that is a problem in my case.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve values of particular fields which are changed in subsequent stages, use `$set` to duplicate those values into new fields.

To retrieve the result set exactly as it exists after the 8th stage, send the first 8 stages as their own pipeline.

Comment: "`send the first 8 stages as their own pipeline.`" but then the 8 stages will run twice, right? It does not seem very performatic, is there an alternative for that?

Comment: Perform the calculations of the remaining stages in your application.